# Trying to add a featured image to a blog profile page in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, profiles

I create profile page for all my bloggers, now I want all of them to be show on this page : http://www.montrealguidecondo.ca/news/blog_profile/. I can see there name but I can see there picture, is there a way to add feature image to a profile page so there picture is gonna be show on the page?

thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the theme, and if you are creating a page for each blogger, there is usually an add featured image button in the bottom right (bottom of the side bar on the right) of each of the bloggers pages that should do what you want.

Comment: There is not that bottom, but I was wandering if I could add it by adding a plugin or something like that

Comment: What theme are you using and does the theme name that page anything specific?

Comment: I'm using personal by webinane : http://themeforest.net/item/personal-best-blog-cv-and-video-wordpress-theme/9211924 . The theme did not name the page anything it is only : /blog_profile/

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to do this if there isn' an option in the bottom right. I would recommend either viewing the documentation and seeing what you can find or emailing support@webinane.com for help (the developers of the theme will help you)

Comment: thanks that why i did but they did not give my a decent answer. They told me to install Easy Author Image Plugin wich didn't do the trick. But thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

As you want image of your bloggers to display on a particular page, then 1st try to install "**User Photo**" plugin. It is very simple to install. After that just go to the user section in admin panel. Click on EDIT of a particular blogger and provide his/her image under User Photo section. After that you only have to use `<?php userphoto_the_author_thumbnail() ?>` to call the image of particular blogger on your required area. I hope it will solve your issue, If not then just msg back. Thanks.